Failed to fetch `proof_size` in runtime via `storage_proof_size` hostfunction
I'm trying to call the cumulus_primitives_storage_weight_reclaim::get_proof_size() within the runtime pallet in the Frontier repo via the newly added host function at https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/polkadot_sdk_docs/guides/enable_pov_reclaim/index.html. However, it seems to not work. I have no idea what the reason might be.
My draft PR: https://github.com/darwinia-network/frontier/pull/24
The log output indicates that get_proof_size is always None. From the documentation, I suspect this is caused by a missing ProofSizeExt registration.
/// Interface that provides access to the current storage proof size.
///
/// Should return the current storage proof size if [`ProofSizeExt`] is registered. Otherwise, needs
/// to return u64::MAX.
#[runtime_interface]
pub trait StorageProofSize {
    /// Returns the current storage proof size.
    fn storage_proof_size(&mut self) -> u64 {
        self.extension::<ProofSizeExt>()
            .map_or(PROOF_RECORDING_DISABLED, |e| e.storage_proof_size())
    }
}

if self.config.enable_import_proof_recording {
    runtime_api.record_proof();
    let recorder = runtime_api.proof_recorder().expect("Proof recording is enabled in the line above; qed.");
    runtime_api.register_extension(ProofSizeExt::new(recorder)); // here
}

However, I have updated new_full_parts to new_full_parts_record_import and set enable_import_proof_recording to true. However, there was no success.

After some investment, this can be resolved by changing ProposerFactory::new(...) to ProposerFactory::with_proof_recording().
